# What router bits do I buy?

Tags: tools, routers

I have bought this router: https://www.dewalt.co.uk/product/dcw604nt-xj/18v-xr-brushless-8mm-14-router-bare-unit

I assume the "8mm" in the description refers to the size of the bit I can use. Do I need to buy DeWalt branded bits or will any fit?

Comment: Online reviews and manual suggest that you get 2 collets -- 8mm and 1/4", so verify that and buy whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Any router bit that fits the router collet (or collets, for more capable routers with larger and smaller collets) should work. In a few cases you have to make sure the maximum rated speed of the bit (typically for large diameter bits) is not less than your router's speed (or speed setting, if adjustable speed.)

The [description of that model](https://www.dewalt.co.uk/product/dcw604nt-xj/18v-xr-brushless-8mm-14-router-bare-unit) states :

> (1) 8mm Collet (¼" GB)

Which either means you get a 1/4" collet (6.35mm) in Great Britain, or the 8mm size collet (0.315 inches) is delusionally **called** 1/4" in Great Britain (I don't know which, and it would matter.) A mere 26% difference in diameter...

Comment: Be aware that larger-radius router bits *MUST* not be used handheld; panel-raising bits, for example, can only be safely used with the machine mounted in a router table. Read and follow the directions; routers have almost unlimited uses (if you can afford almost unlimited bits), but their high speed of rotation means you can get into trouble very quickly too. CAREFUL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any 8mm/ 1/4 inch shaft bit.